# For loop with strange condition

Tags: javascript

I came across this snippet reading MDN's tutorial ["A re-introduction to JavaScript (JS tutorial)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript):

```
function countChars(elm) {
  if (elm.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE
    return elm.nodeValue.length;
  }
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) {
    count += countChars(child);
  }
  return count;
}
```

What I don't understand is the for loop statement. Specifically, the condition statement `child = elm.childNodes[i]`. I always learned that the condition in a loop should be a logical one. For me, that's an assignment.

What am I losing?

Comment: Assignment always returns the assigned value. If the element is not found, it would be `null`, or in this case `undefined`, and as `null` and `undefined` are both falsy, the assigment, or rather the assigned value it returns, can also be used as a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of `for` loop here is the value of the **assignment oprator `=`** (which is in other words the value `elm.childNodes[i]`).

```js
var a,
    assignmentOperatorValue = ( a = 5 );
//                            ^^^^^^^^^ this yields 5 which is then assigned to assignmentOperatorValue, you can even pass that value to a function like: func(a = 5);
    
console.log(assignmentOperatorValue);
```

If `elm.childNodes[i]` is an element (truthy value) then the condition is `true`.

If `elm.childNodes[i]` is `undefined` (falsy value) then the condition is `false`.

Answer (score 5):

When the `i` in `child = elm.childNodes[i]` is bigger than the length of the array, the deklaration gets evalutated to `undefined`. And in js `undefined` is equal to false `Boolean(undefined) -> false`.

Because of that, this is a boolean equation.

That kind of equation is danger because if the array contains an element that is equal to false (`null, 0, false`), the loop will stop without iterating all elements.

Comment: It's not **equal** to `false`, it's ***falsy***, which is different ! As `childNodes` returns elements, it would never return `false` or `0`

Comment: `Boolean(undefined)  === false` -> true
Thats feels like equal for me

Comment: @adeneo `var a=[false]; for(var i =0; child = a[i]; i++){ console.log("this will never be seen")}` in this case it returns false with the first element.

Comment: But `undefined === false` is not true, so it's not strictly equal unless you convert it to a boolean, which means it's not equal, it's **falsy**, not `false`

Comment: In your second example, passing in `0` will of course void the loop, but `childNodes` doesn't return zeros, it returns DOM nodes

Comment: It returns DOM nodes until it returns `undefined` which is equal to false, is i said. It`s of course not strictly equal to false but but that is not importantant for a boolean equation. There is only `true` or `false`, a bit can be `1` or `0`, a logical state like `falsy`doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to recognize that this is an assignment, and I personally would avoid writing a loop like this because it can be confusing to other developers. However, it actually works because every assignment expression returns the value that was assigned. For example, after the following statement, both `a` and `b` will have a value of `1`:

```
var a, b;
a = b = 1;
```

If `elm.childNodes` is an array, then `child = elm.childNodes[i]` will both assign `child`'s value and return the value of `elm.childNodes[i]`. If `elm.childNodes[i]` is truthy, then the loop will continue. Otherwise it will break.

So this loop could break when it reaches an index higher than the last value in the array, or if the value at an index is `0`, `false`, `null` or any other falsy value in the JavaScript language. It's likely that the programmer is just assuming that all values in the array will have to be valid objects that won't evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops are built by 3 parts:

- initialization
- condition
- final-expression

In your case - the `condition` part is `child = elm.childNodes[i];`.

When accessing element of list that is our-of-range - the value you will get is `undefined` and the condition will result in breaking the loop.