# trying to understand for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am implementing HTML5 drag and drop using JavaScript, and I have found some sample code that is actually working. But this one piece of code doesn't make sense to me. What is this snippet of code doing?

```
// fetch FileList object
var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

// process all File objects
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

}
```

I am confused by the FOR loop.  I understand it's basic use:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
```

But how does this work?  What is `var i = 0, f`?

Comment: It's a variable declaration. Is there something in particular you don't understand about it?

Comment: I just don't understand how it ever knows it's at the end of the loop.

Comment: So you're asking about `f = files[i]` as the condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop with strange condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044054/for-loop-with-strange-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization expression `var i = 0, f` is declaring two variables, `i` and `f`. The `i` is initialized to zero, while the `f` is left uninitialized. Then, for each iteration through the loop, the value at position `i` in the `files` array is assigned to `f`. This result of this assignment is evaluated as the loop conditional. At the end of each iteration the integer value of `i` is incremented by one.

At a high level this just iterates over values in the `files` array, assigning each to `f` for use in the loop body. Once an index in the `files` array is reached that does not have a truthy value the loop is exited. An assumption is made here that all valid values in the `files` array will be truthy.

Comment: OK, so say I have 2 files, the third time through it will set f = files[2] which doesn't exist so it will automatically stop. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, you got it. The result of `f = files[i]` will be `undefined`, which evaluates to false and causes the loop to exit.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I couldn't find that documented anywhere. I tried to +1 your answer but don't have enough reputation for it to show up.

Comment: As an alternative you could _accept_ my answer if it was helpful to you. :)